# How to use Python Requests package to POST payload of "textarea"?

Tags: python, python-requests

Suppose I have a website with this piece of html code in it:

```
    <textarea id="id1" name="name1" class="class1" style="width: 230px;
    height: 40px; border: 1px solid #c1c1c1; margin: 20px 25px; 
    padding: 0px; resize: none;  display: none; "></textarea>
```

How can I use POST method of Python "Requests" package to pass an argument of a text in this form? What kind of payload should it be - should the key of my data be "name1", "text" or something else? I am a bit at loss here.

Thanks!

Comment: The key should be the name of the field. In your example it's `name1`.

Comment: Use browser to do the same action and see what request is being sent.
You could see HTTP request being made in Network Section on Dev Tools.

Comment: use DevTools in browser to see request from some page. Use http://httpbin.org/post/ to test own request - it sends back all your request . And then you can compare both and see differences.

Comment: Great, thanks @saurabhbaid! Chrome makes it very simple to track HTTP request indeed.